# custom navigation using N2CMS, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, n2cms

I need to create a dynamically generated menu for an E-Commerce web site. It would be horizontal or vertical or both using N2CMS. I have tried to use TopMenu but could not go far. Has anyone implemented like this using N2CMS, MVC ? ANy help or direction would be helpful.

for example here you can see that the menu on top and left 
http://www.webhallen.com/canon

Spel Film ....

Spel 
Film
. 
. 
.

They might be the same control and setting could affect the layout form horizontal to vertical etc.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom control called [Menu](http://api.n2cms.com/_mvc_2_mvc_templates_2_details_2_controls_2_menu_8cs_source.html), you can modify it to fit your needs.

Besides, these are some related discussions:

- [Drop-Down Menu/Navigation Items](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/253775)
- [Removing Parts from Tree.From Navigation Menu](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/264897)
- [building two types of navigation](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/32173)
- [Footer navigation](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/272164)

About the vertical and horizontal menus issue, it is a JQuery and CSS thing.
You can use [FastMenu](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jfastmenu) or [SimplejQueryDropDowns](http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/) as I did.